# How to set min width on GtkScrollbar?

Tags: css, python-2.7, gtk3

I want to develop new features in [Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io) music player.

I need to increase size of specific scrollbar.
There's a function already exists to apply css to a widget:

```
def add_css(widget, css):
    """Add css for the widget, overriding the theme.

    Can raise GLib.GError in case the css is invalid
    """

    if not isinstance(css, bytes):
        css = css.encode("utf-8")

    provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    provider.load_from_data(css)
    context = widget.get_style_context()
    context.add_provider(provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

So I try to apply css as this:

```
    self.scrollwin = sw = ScrolledWindow()
    sw.set_shadow_type(Gtk.ShadowType.IN)
    #get scrollbar       
    vscrollbar = sw.get_vscrollbar()

    # 1rst attempt
    # qltk.add_css(vscrollbar, '* slider {min-width: 20px;}')

    #2nd attempt
    qltk.add_css(vscrollbar, 'scrollbar.vertical slider {min-width: 20px;}')
```

I've got same error with 2 attempts:

> 'min-width' is not a valid property name (3)

**Update 1**

I try @Herbalist solution, scrollbar component is resized but "slider" always have same size. It add spaces on right and on left of "slider".

```
vscrollbar.set_size_request(50,-1)
```

Is it possible to resize slider of scrollbar ?

Screenshot of result (I outline part of scrollbar in green):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to success with css, so I use deprecated method:

> GtkRange:slider-width has been deprecated since version 3.20 and
>   should not be used in newly-written code.
>
> Use the min-height/min-width CSS properties on the slider element. The
>   value of this style property is ignored.

As this:

```
qltk.add_css(vscrollbar, '* {-GtkRange-slider-width:40px}')
```

Answer (score -1):

get_vscrollbar() returns a Gtk.Widget so you could try setting the "width-request" property